# The 'oracle' dialect with current database version settings does not support empty inserts

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, sqlalchemy

Does anyone know what this error means? Below is class method that returns error sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: The 'oracle' dialect with current database version settings does not support empty inserts.

Im using same classmethod in sqlserver and it works. how to bypass this in oracle using sqlalchemy orm?

```
def insertr(self, tablename, data, schema=None):
    def convert_nan(v):
        if pd.isnull(v) or pd.isna(v):
            v = None
        return v

    class DbTable(object):
        pass

    engine = self.engine
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    table = Table(tablename, metadata, autoload=True, quote=True, schema=schema)
    mapper(DbTable, table)
    DbTable.__getattribute__(DbTable, self.primary_key)

    insert_rows = [{k: convert_nan(v) for k, v in check_ir.items()} for check_ir in data]
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(DbTable, insert_rows)

    session.commit()
    session.flush()
```

and data that im trying to insert looks like :

```
[{'coll': 10, 'col2': 'value'}, {'col1': 20, 'col2': 'value'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround for this problem so if anyone stumbleupon same issue here is the code:

```
def insertr(self, tablename, data, schema=None):
    def convert_nan(v):
        if pd.isnull(v) or pd.isna(v):
            v = None
        return v

    engine = self.engine
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    table = Table(tablename, metadata, autoload=True, quote=True, schema=schema)
    insert_rows = [{k.lower(): convert_nan(v) for k, v in check_ir.items()} for check_ir in data]
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        for insert_row in insert_rows:
            connection.execute(table.insert().values(**insert_row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed below checklist to resolve the same error:

1. Check the `column names` and `dictionary keys` (dict to be inserted) are matching (case-sensitive match)
2. Some `database objects` like a trigger, procedure is trying to insert a value in a column which does not exists.
3. Trying to insert a none value for a `NUN-NULL` column